# lion chasing a zebra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a zebra at coordinate (0,0) and a lion at (-1,0). The zebra runs towards the right in the shape of a sine wave. The lion is running towards where the zebra is at any point in time, so it is not anticipating any of its turns. When will the lion catch its prey if it is 10% faster than the zebra ? Let's say their speeds are 1 unit/second and 1.1 unit/second. Is it true that it'll never fully catch up if their speeds are identical ?

I have no idea how to solve this and hope that the tag added is not misleading.

Comment: What is the amplitude of the sine wave that the zebra runs?

Comment: It is the function sin(x), so amplitude is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${\bf p}$ and ${\bf z}$ be the momentary positions of the lion and the zebra. Introduce a momentary $(\bar x,\bar y)$ coordinate system with its origin at ${\bf p}$ and the positive $\bar x$-axis in the direction of the vector ${\bf z}-{\bf p}$. Then ${\bf z}=(r,0)$, where $r$ denotes the momentary distance between the two. Let the speed of the zebra be $1$ and the speed of the lion be $\lambda>1$. When in the next moment $\arg\dot{\bf z}=\theta$ in the $(\bar x,\bar y)$ coordinate system then 
$$\dot{\bf p}=(\lambda,0),\qquad\dot{\bf z}=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\ .$$
It follows that
$${d\over dt}|{\bf z}-{\bf p}|^2=2({\bf z}-{\bf p})\cdot(\dot{\bf z}-\dot{\bf p})=2(r,0)\cdot(\cos\theta-\lambda,\sin\theta)=2r(\cos\theta-\lambda)\ .$$
Therefore we obtain
$${dr\over dt}={d\over dt}\sqrt{|{\bf z}-{\bf p}|^2}={2r(\cos\theta-\lambda)\over 2|{\bf z}-{\bf p}|}=\cos\theta-\lambda\ ,$$
as intuitively expected. It follows that
$${dr\over dt}\leq-(\lambda-1)\ ;$$
and since $r=1$ at the start we can infer that the lion catches the zebra in time $$T\leq{1\over\lambda-1}\ ,$$
whatever curve the zebra is pursuing.

When $\lambda=1$ and the zebra just runs away from the lion he will of course never catch it. For the case of a sine curve, however, things might be different.